# Using SQL in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax, average, limit

After importing a spreadsheet into BigQuery, I sometimes get an error message that the SQL syntax used to query the data is incorrect. Any guide on how best to structure my SQL commands?

I was trying to get the average precipitation within a time frame, using the commands below;

```
SELECT 
 AVG(precipitation)
 FROM `my-quaded-project-51454.demos.nyc_weather` 
  WHERE
  date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: I don't know bigquery, but `date` is likely a keyword that needs to be escaped (or the column renamed). Also, why `LIMIT 4`, you can only get one row. Finally, you should be aware your current `BETWEEN` would exclude `'2020-06-30 12:00:00'`, if your ``date`` column should include times.

Comment: If you sometimes get an error and you want to know "how best to structure my SQL commands", you should learn SQL. There are plenty tutorials and courses available

Comment: The problem is likely to be with the data.  Take a file that is failing and create the smallest set of data from it that fails.  From there you will notice either the date column does not always contain date or the precipitation column does not always contain a number.  One other option would be to cast the columns to date and numeric first to make sure.  If you can reduce the data down to a small failing sample set, then add it to the question and you'll be able to get more help

Comment: @HoneyBadger, thanks for your suggestion. The query ran, as soon as deleted the LIMIT 4 command, and yes I will learn to improve on my sequel prowess.

Comment: @DarylWenman-Bateson, I appreciate your recommendations.